# How to model a one-mandatory-of-many relationship

Tags: database, database-design

**I have following class model that I'm quite happy with:**

[image: Class Model]

A `Whole` has a special mandatory `Part`. Furthermore it has a collection of parts, that contains at least the mandatory part, but may contain many more. In the OO model parts don't need to know where they belong.

**So now I came up with this RDB model:**

```
Whole:
   id - primary key
   special_part_id - non-nullable, unique, foreign key to Part

Part:
   id - primary key
   whole_id - non-nullable, foreign key to Whole
```

The only constraint that is not checked here is `Whole = Whole.special_mandatory_part.whole`.

However, with this table layout I'm not even able to insert rows. Might be worth mentioning that I'm using an ORM, but even with plain SQL I would not know how to do it.

So my questions are:

- Is this DB design bad, and if so why?
- <del>If not, how would you insert rows?</del>
- What design would you recommend and why?

I'm aware of [this very similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219343/db-design-circular-references-for-the-one-of-many-case). However, because of the `not null` constraint my problem is slightly different (worse I'd say) and I'm not satisfied with the given answers.

**UPDATE** Just found an answer on [how to insert rows with a table layout like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11577631/380229).

Answer (score 2):

First the evident errors:

- `special_part_id` in `Whole` shouldn't exist
- `whole_id` in `Part` should be a FK to `Whole`, not to user

That way the relationships is that `Whole` is comprised of one or more parts.

Now to clarify something:

- **Conceptually you can model a one-to-many relationship that is mandatory both ways, but physically it's imposible to implement.** You can only implement it being mandatory on one side and not-mandatory in the other. In this case, it's mandatory on the Part side, but optional on the Whole side.

Comment: `whole_id` being a FK to `User` was a c&p error, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I agree.  If a part is to be treated specially, Part table should have a flag column indicating as such.

Comment: @Neil what about performance when using a flag and having a large number of parts?

Comment: @user61852: so are you suggesting the same solution as Neil? It just feels so wrong to me ;)

Comment: @raphinesse I don't see Neil's answer. I only see mine as of now. why you say mine is the same as Neil's ?

Comment: @user61852 Neil commented on this solution of yours. So to rephrase my question from before: what design would you suggest and why is mine so bad?

Comment: @raphinesse In my answer I point at some errors.

Comment: @raphinesse Database tables share zero or one relationship between them, not more than that.  Having more than one relationship in the same direction doesn't make sense, and having one in the opposite direction is problematic because you create a cyclic dependency.  It isn't that you *can't*, it is that you *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 0):

Stop trying to model business rules in your database, it is a time sink that will get you no where. It is also distracting you from modeling these rules where it is appropriate to do so, your business object layer.

Databases have one job only, and that is to persist your application's state.

Please do not take this to mean that basic referential integrity checks are not a good idea; they are. But, when it comes to the minutia, like X must have one Y, that is the role of your application.

It might be more flexible to add a *IsPartRequired (bit)* column to your part table and let the application do the enforcement. It might also be possible that you are trying to put something in the DB which does not need to be there at all.